# Is there an SQL query pattern I can use to compare records in the same table without repeating?

Tags: sql

I find that this scenario comes up when analyzing imported data that doesn't adhere to application constraints.

An example of a table called `Account`:

```
id
customer_name
customer_number
(other arbitrary columns)
```

When looking for duplicate customer_number values, for example, I would join two instances of the same table. It's what I've long done and never learned another way to do this:

```sql
select a1.id, a1.customer_name, a1.customer_number, a2.id, a2.customer_name, a2.customer_number
from account a1 join account a2 on a1.customer_number = a2.customer_number
where a1.id <> a2.id;
```

This produces the desired results. However, when record with id x (rx) and record with id y (ry) fit the criteria, will produce the result list of rx = ry and ry = rx, so I get two lines that come to the same thing.

Is there a better way to query this type of comparison without producing duplicates?

I have searched for this answer many times over the years, but my searches have never yielded what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi - can’t you just count by the column which may have duplicates and use HAVING > 1 ?

Comment: Just like NickW said you can `count`, or use `a1.id < a2.id` with other comparisons to avoid the duplicate result lines.

Answer (score 0):

The quick modification of your existing code to avoid (rx,ry) and (ry,rx) duplication is to use `a1.id > a2.id` instead of `a1.id <> a2.id` in the where clause,

Here is the query:

```
select a1.id, a1.customer_name, a1.customer_number, a2.id, a2.customer_name, a2.customer_number
from account a1 
join account a2 
on a1.customer_number = a2.customer_number
where a1.id > a2.id;
```

You can also use a [group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) operator to have all customer_number with multiple id and join back to orignal table to get the list of ids linked with the those customer numbers.

Here is the query:

```
select a.customer_number, a.id, a1.customer_name
from 
account a  
join 
(select customer_number from account group by customer_number having count(1) > 1) n
on a.customer_number = n.customer_number
order by a.customer_number, a.id
```

At last, if you are using a DB Engine(PostgreSQL,Presto,Spark,BigQuery,...) which support complex data type(array and/or map), this can be done in a single group by operator with a having clause. I provide an example below with Presto [map_agg()](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#map-aggregate-functions) function.

Here is the query:

```
select 
     customer_number, 
     map_agg(id, customer_name) as id_name_map
from account 
group by customer_number 
having count(1) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the examples. This is what I needed to see.